# How to modify the function below to parse a url?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have written a function in Google Tag Manager, where I get the last segment of the url (http://www.testsite.com/amazon:32/) which works great. Seeing the example code below displays "amazon:32", however now I only want to just display "amazon" and store "32" elsewhere. How can I modify the function below to do this?

```js
<script>
function lastSegment() {
var clickurl = "http://www.testsite.com/amazon:32/";
var brandName = clickurl.match(/\/([^\/]+)[\/]?$/);
brandName[1] = brandName[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + brandName[1].slice(1); //capitalize first lett of brand name
alert (lastSegment[1]);
}
</script>
```

Thanks again for any help!

Comment: You can use `split` on `:`. Like `brandName[1].split(':')[0]`. Btw you have invalid code up there..

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works great!

Comment: I assume in practice `clickurl` is a dynamic value.  Have you considered what happens if there is no match? `brandName[1]` will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid firing a Regexp just for that. Basically, you should just use `url.lastIndexOf('/')` in your case, it's way more efficient and readable.

```
function getBrandName(url) {
  if (url.endsWith('/')) {
    url = url.slice(0, url.length - 1);
  }

  var slashIndex = url.lastIndexOf('/');
  if (slashIndex === -1) { return {}; }

  var [ brand, number ] = url.slice(slashIndex + 1).split(':');
  brand = brand[0].toUpperCase() + brand.slice(1);
  return { brand, number };
}
```

Here is the output when used with your url:

```
> getBrandName("http://www.testsite.com/amazon:32/")
{ brand: 'amazon', number: '32' }
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I understand your concern too. Tried your code however I receive this error:

"Error at line 11, character 7: this language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: destructuring. Use --language_in=ECMASCRIPT6 or ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT to enable ES6 features."

Comment: What browser/nodejs version are you using?

Comment: Chrome and this is being done within Google Tag Manager

Comment: Any idea? Your thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: This just maybe an issue with how Google Tag Manager does this? @Aur

Comment: Sorry, I was off for a few days. Indeed, latest Chrome versions support ES6 syntax since a long time already. Can you display your Chrome version (in preferences)? Mine is 53.0.